# Trying to implement the "How to create Tabs" using Node.js, ejs and Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to build a website following this Tutorial ([Building Web Applications Using Node.js](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-web-application-using-node-js-part-5/)) and currently using HTML, ejs, Node.js (+express), yarn and javascript. I would like to  integrate some Tabs like [How TO - Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp).

But I am struggeling to control the hiding and showing tabs from the js routing file. I did not find a way to control the tab divs by the express router. Could anyone please help me or point me into a direction?

Thank you.

PS. My plan is to use parts of the existing Node.js and HTML artifacts to build an app using Electron, Web Assembly and Rust. That is why I use all those things, which might seem a bit overkill at first.